# Angular2 RC - troubleshot disabled button

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, disabled-input

these is my first question here, so please tell me if i've done something wrong so i could fix it :)

I've got some problem to make the [diabled] tag work correctly on a button in my form.

here my template :

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
      <label class="omwave">Identifiant</label>
      <input type="text" class="omwave" [(ngModel)]="login" placeholder="Identifiant" name="login" required>
      <label class="omwave">Mot de passe</label>
      <div class="input-group omwave">
        <input type="password" class="input-group-field omwave" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" name="password" required>
        <div class="input-group-button">
          <button type="submit" (click)="goLogin()" value="submit" class="" [disabled]="!isValid"><img width="25px" src="imgs/start_service.png" alt="login_button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

And here my component  :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, NG_VALIDATORS, Validators, Control} from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'app/core/templates/login.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class LoginComponent {
  protected login: string;
  protected password: string;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

When my two input login and password are empty, got the ng-invalid property on it and the button is disable.
But if i fill the inputs, they got the ng-valid property but my button still reamin disabled, and i d'ont know why because the form is valid when the inputs are filled.
If someone has an idea please :)
If you need any other informations, i'll try to answer it.

Thanks for reading.

Regards,

Comment: you can not disabled submit button on isValid.. Rather you can do on form.dirty check .... Why so even a single change in field make form dirty ... but after change user should know validations on the current form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following based on inline form support of Angular2:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
  <label class="omwave">Identifiant</label>
  <input type="text" class="omwave" [(ngModel)]="login" 
         placeholder="Identifiant" name="login"
         ngControl="name" required> <--------
  <label class="omwave">Mot de passe</label>
  <div class="input-group omwave">
    <input type="password" class="input-group-field omwave" 
         [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Mot de passe"
         ngControl="password" name="password" required> <-------
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <button type="submit" (click)="goLogin()" value="submit" 
          class="" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid"> <------
        <img width="25px" src="imgs/start_service.png" alt="login_button">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In your case, I don't know how the `isValid` property is handled and to what it corresponds. You can directly rely on the form state (`loginForm`) and its `valid` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thierry ! :)
Adding the [ngControl]="login" and the [ngControl]="password" on my inputs and swicthing the [disabled]="!isValid" to [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" make it works really good !

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work,

```
<button type="submit" (click)="goLogin()" value="submit" class="" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid"><img width="25px" src="imgs/start_service.png" alt="login_button"></button>
```

Comment: sadly no micronyks, i've tried this cause i've seen it in another post but doesn't work :s